# Find Free Appointment Slots given Opening Times and Booked Appointment Times

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Any ideas to make it better or more efficient? any edge cases that are not covered?
Opening times:

```
const openingTimes = [
  {
    date: "2020-01-01",
    open: "08:00",
    close: "18:00",
  },
  {
    date: "2020-01-02",
    open: "08:00",
    close: "18:00",
  },
  {
    date: "2020-01-03",
    open: "08:00",
    close: "18:00",
  },
];
```

Booked Appointments (busy times):

```
const bookedAppointments = [
  {
    date: "2020-01-01",
    time: "08:00",
  },
  {
    date: "2020-01-01",
    time: "11:00",
  },
  {
    date: "2020-01-03",
    time: "09:00",
  },
  {
    date: "2020-01-03",
    time: "10:00",
  },
  {
    date: "2020-01-03",
    time: "11:00",
  },
];
```

Simple Solution:

```
const slot_duration = 60 * 60 * 1000;
const busyTimes = bookedAppointments.map((b) =>
  Date.parse(`${b.date} ${b.time}`)
);
function isBusy(t) {
  return busyTimes.some((b) => t >= b && t < b + slot_duration);
}

function getFreeSlots() {
  const slots = {
    free: [],
    busy: [],
  };

  openingTimes.forEach((o) => {
    const start = Date.parse(`${o.date} ${o.open}`);
    const end = Date.parse(`${o.date} ${o.close}`);

    for (let i = start; i <= end; i += slot_duration) {
      if (isBusy(i)) {
        slots.busy.push(new Date(i).toLocaleString());
      } else {
        slots.free.push(new Date(i).toLocaleString());
      }
    }
  });

  return slots;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of parsing and re-parsing. Better to fix up the Dates once and be done with it. Write down the requirements, as there seems to be some unspoken prohibition about seeing this in a booking: `time: "11:30"`. Explicitly sort Dates, and then exploit binary search or [2-way merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm#K-way_merging). [Hmm, bunch of recent edits to the OP.]

Answer (score 1):

I think a data restructure would make management a lot easier. `openingTimes` could use numbers instead of strings for times so parsing is easier. `bookedAppointments` could change syntax to have dates as keys(then timeslots as keys):

```
const bookedAppointments = {
  "2020-01-01": {
    "08:00": "Davey Jones", // the value could be more complex or point to user _id
    "08:30": '',
    ...
    "11:00": "Lou Poole",
    ...
  },
  "2020-01-03": {
    "08:00": '',
    "08:30": '',
    "09:00": 'Stack Over Flow',
    "09:30": '',
    "10:00": 'Michael Scott',
    "10:30": '',
    "11:00": 'Ata',
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

<sub>Another option for `bookdAppointments` is keys of date-hour keys: `'2020-01-03 09:00': 'User'`, which would eliminate the nested structure, but would have a similarly easy check in `isBusy`</sub>

If `slots` followed a similar pattern then `isBusy` would basically be checking if object had key value:

```
function isBusy(date, timeSlot) {
  if(!(date in bookedAppointments)) return false;
  return bookedAppointments[date][timeSlot]
}
```

Other edits to get this to work involve changing `slotDuration` percentage of hour and a way to convert number to string time.

```js
const openingTimes = [
  {
    date: "2020-01-01",
    open: 8,
    close: 18,
  },
  {
    date: "2020-01-02",
    open: 8,
    close: 18,
  },
  {
    date: "2020-01-03",
    open: 8,
    close: 18,
  },
];

const bookedAppointments = {
  "2020-01-01":{
    "08:00": "Davey Jones", // the value could be a more complex object with user details or point to user _id
    "11:00": "Lou Poole",
  },
  "2020-01-03":{
    "08:00": '',
    "09:00": 'Stack Over Flow',
    "10:00": 'Michael Scott',
    "11:00": 'Ata',
  },
}

const slot_duration = 1; // in hours

function padZero(string){
  return ("00" + string).slice(-2);
}
function toReadableString(time) {
  if (time < 0)
    time = 0;
  var hrs = Math.floor(time),
    mins = (time - Math.floor(time))*60;
  return `${padZero(hrs)}:${padZero(mins)}`;
}
function isBusy(date, timeSlot) {
  if(!(date in bookedAppointments)) return false;
  return bookedAppointments[date][timeSlot]
}

function getFreeSlots() {
  const slots = {
    free: {},
    busy: {},
  };

  openingTimes.forEach((o) => {
    const start = o.open;
    const end = o.close;
    let t;

    for (let i = start; i <= end; i += slot_duration) {
      t = toReadableString(i);
      if (isBusy(o.date, t)) {
        if(o.date in slots.busy) {
          slots.busy[o.date].push(t);
        } else {
          slots.busy[o.date]=[t]
        }
      } else {
        if(o.date in slots.free) {
          slots.free[o.date].push(t);
        } else {
          slots.free[o.date]=[t]
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return slots;
}
console.log(getFreeSlots())
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Reusable package

A tidy function (class, sort of) that is not polluting global space.  Try a [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE).](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-immediately-invoked-function-expression-iife/#:%7E:text=A%20JavaScript%20immediately%20invoked%20function%20expression%20is%20a,engine%20adds%20the%20function%20to%20the%20global%20object.) It's a bit old school but is very effective. See how that works for you.

Encapsulating "appointments" into a single coherent API makes things sooooo much easier,

#### Appointment object

- Offhand with properties `date`, `time`, `customer`, `isBooked`, `duration`, etc.
- put `isBusy` in there.
- Make a constructor taking that string-thing object and parse to a `Date`.
- override `toString` and add other methods as needed for outputting different formats. Possibly using a string-format expression parameter means one method can do any form.
- Don't add to array here. Lt the Appointments (plural) objet do that.

##### Dates are not strings

Take advantage of built in `Date` functionality. Do all processing, comparisons, arithmetic as `Date`s not strings. Strings only for formatted output, to the console for example.

#### Appointment collection object

- Make a custom list/array/collection of `Appointment`s. There will be only one. No separate "free" & "busy", a property (above) will enable filtering.
- openingTimes.forEach function goes in here, in a constructor is the best place,
- Make a constructor that takes that whole appointment-string-object, makes individual `Date` objects, and checks for overlap as each is added to the array.
- Have `Add` function for individual appointment inclusion. Check for scheduling overlap here.

The `openingTimes` JSON can, and should, be parsed up front, per [@J_H comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/284175/find-free-appointment-slots-given-opening-times-and-booked-appointment-times#comment565166_284175)

##### Terminology

- `Appointment` and `slot` are the same thing. Use the same term everywhere. As written implies these are two different things/concepts, why have different names/terms otherwise?
- `OfficeHours`, not "openingTimes"
- free == not busy OR busy == not free. Don't use two different properties; actually, the point is do not have two independent pieces of code that do the same thing. It's OK if you really want both "free" and "busy" - allowing code have flexible expressiveness - make sure one is written in terms of the other. That is "free" may be coded as `return !busy();`